# Print html image tag not render it using php

Tags: php, html, printing

I want to echo out an `img tag` but i dont want it to render. the goal is for the project manager to upload a file on a `php page` and retrieve the `img html tag` so he can use it in a program.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see your code? "Print" as in "print on paper"? "_its a legitimate question_" I don't even see a question

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars("<img src='test.jpg'>");
echo '</pre>';
```

You have to replace all '<' characters with `&lt;` and all '>' with `&gt`;

> htmlentities — Convert all
>   applicable characters to HTML entities